# Protractor + xvfb + selenium test Hangs on Jenkins

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, jenkins, protractor

I'm having this issue sometimes on my automated tests running  remotely on Jenkins. About **30% of the times**.

**The error:**

**Tests hangs** after this line: 
"**I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver**"

It **gets stuck** at this step indefinitely and I have to stop execution (manually) or wait to timeout to take control of it.

I tried several known solutions that i found on this site but nothing changed on my results.

**My config:**

Ubuntu OS 14.04.5 on a headless cloud storage system.

xvfb

Jenkins 1.656

selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1

chromedriver_2.24linux64

geckodriver-v0.9.0

nodejs v0.10.37

node v6.3.1

npm 3.10.3

protractor Version 4.0.9

grunt-cli v1.2.0

grunt v0.4.5

jasmine v2.5.2

jasmine-core v2.5.2

**Jenkins Job Config:**

Jenkins downloads my test project from github and runs the following commands on Project's shell:

**node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt testName:parameters** 
(I don't want to run grunt globally, thats why i execute it in this way.)

Is there anything i can try in order to solve this hang issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would probably use docker to run the tests rather than just using Jenkins so that you can check if the same thing happens on your local box.

Comment: I solved this issue by adding this environment variable to every jenkins job that was failing: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null

Comment: @DamianAttademo,can you please help to understand what your above solution actually does?